# Is Change tracking feature available in PostgreSQL similar to that of Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Is Change tracking feature available in PostgreSQL similar to that of Microsoft SQL Server. Actually we are using PostgreSQL and MS SQL together and want to move changed data from PostgreSQL to MS SQL using change tracking. How to achieve this in best possible and lightweight way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is something like that.

It's called [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html) and is part of the infrastructure for [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). While logical replication can only be used between two Postgres instances, logical decoding can be used independently of that (if you write the code to consume the messages).

Tools like [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) make use of that